# AJAX calls only working once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#username').change(check_username);
    });

    function check_username() {
      $("#check_username").html('<img src="images/site/ajax-loader.gif" />username avilable??').delay(5000);
      var usernametotest = $('#username').val();    
      $.post("backend/username_available.php", { username: usernametotest})
       .done(function(data) {
         $("#check_username").replaceWith(data);
       });
    }
</script>
```

I use this code for checking with AJACX the availability of a username in my form.
It works perfect but just once. When an username is occupied and I change the username, no AJAX checks are done after the first one? The text "username already exists" (in the variable data), is not replaced by "username ok".

This JavaScript is added just before the `</html>` tag.

Comment: have you looked into developer's tools that the subsequent request are really not generated? I suspect server might always respond with "username already exists".

Comment: in `done` function whats the `data` variable? plain text or html

Comment: Use "live" or "on"  on changes after DOM Load successfully

Comment: In Firebug I see that the subsequent calls are being made and i get the right anwer back (in plain text). So the problem seems to be that the div check_username is not updating anymore after the first call. the last part (delay has been removed, only needed to test if my gifloader img showed up)

Comment: You're replacing `#check_username` with whatever you receive from the post request. Has the new element the same id?

Comment: why has my question been downvoted?? Pitty i can't see by whom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine - see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frTaM/) with an alert on the `usernametotest` value for more visibility

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#username').change(check_username);
});

function check_username(){

    $("#check_username").html('username avilable??').delay(5000);
    var usernametotest = $('#username').val();

    alert('posting username ' + usernametotest);

    $.post("backend/username_available.php", { username: usernametotest} )
        .done(function(data) {
            $("#check_username").replaceWith( data );
        });  
}
```

The post requests are being made every time with the correct payload, so no problems there (check browser developer tools e.g. Network tab / XHR in Chrome)

Must be an issue with the response coming back from `backend/username_available.php`? Check the response of the first request vs the rest, and the difference and hence the problem will probably jump out at you.

Comment: Yessssssssssssss! I did not realize i was replacing the comeplete div instead only the content of the div. Added the div into the answer of the backend file and it works like a champ. Thank you al for your thoughts!!!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you **replace an element**... and here you do just that...

```
$("#check_username").replaceWith( data );
```

**all those element's handlers are lost**. So `change()` no longer works. To be able to use it again, you just need to bind again the element after it has been rewritten:

```
$('#username').change(check_username);
```

Or bind the handler to a parent and delegate it:

```
$('#username').parent().on('click', '#username', check_username);
```

(I feel that a class selector would work better - call it superstition on my part)

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
$('#username').on('change', function() {

  // write your code here

});
```

Comment: live is deprecated with jQuery 1.7

Comment: and removed as for jq 1.9

Comment: Why should he use live? He does not replace #username during the ajax processing so using "change" is allright.

Comment: because .on is better /s